# NGINX - Can't set content-type header

Tags: nginx, svg, mime-types, mime

I'm using `nginx/1.10-3` on Debian.

I have a file named logo.img which infact is an svg.

I've modified `/etc/nginx/mime.types` to include the `.img` as an extension for the svg file type: `image/svg+xml   svg svgz img;`

But the headers of the file served is still `application/octet-stream`

For some bizarre reason, i've been asked to serve the `.img` file as an svg for a logo on a site, i've got it to work on Apache2 using mime magic. But, as far as i know, that doesn't exist on NGINX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/etc/nginx/mime.types` file already contains a mapping for URIs ending with `.img`, which is set to `application/octet-stream`.

When you edit the file, did must also remove this existing mapping.

---

Alternatively, you can override the content-type for a single URI.

For example:

```
root /path/to/root;
...
location = /images/logo.img {
    types {}
    default_type image/svg+xml;
}
```

Comment: can't believe it was that easy! Thank you

Comment: +1 for mentioning types {}, I needed to open a page where links ended in .jpg but the content was actually HTML.